# Swift Xcode6 beta6 regex

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to get the characters using regex

I want to get "CDE"

```
var results : NSMutableArray;
var baseString = "ABCDEFG"
var regexp  = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "AB.*?FG", options: nil, error: nil)
var match : NSArray = regexp.matchesInString(baseString, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0,countElements(baseString)));

for matches in match {      
    results.addObject(sampleString.substringWithRange(matches.rangeAtIndex(2)));
}
println(results);//print"CDE"
```

but I get error.
ERROR→

```
results.addObject(sampleString.substringWithRange(matches.rangeAtIndex(2)));
NSRange' is not convertible to 'Range<String.Index>'
```

my english isn't good.sorry..
please help me...

Comment: Try using NSMakeRange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression is incorrect, the match will be the entire string. Instead use: (?<=AB).*?(?=FG).

Documantation: ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Notes:

```
(?<=AB) means preceded by AB  
(?=FG)  means followed by FG
```

These do not capture the matched portion.

Example code:

```
var baseString = "ABCDEFG"
var pattern = "(?<=AB).*?(?=FG)"
if let range = baseString.rangeOfString(pattern, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    let found = baseString.substringWithRange(range)
    println("found: \(found)")
}
```

Output:

> found: CDE