# extract the image link from xkcd.com in swift

Tags: ios, parsing, uiwebview, swift, xcode6

If you visit xkcd.com it will display a webcomic image. Below it, the direct link to that image is showed below it, for example:

> Image URL (for hotlinking/embedding):
>   http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/horse.png

Now, how do I parse the page to extract the image link from the page and put it into NSURL variable, using Xcode 6 and Swift, so I can make my UIWebView display only the image rather than the whole page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression. See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548790/451475) for details.

Pay particular attention to the Notes:
(?<=) Ex: (?<=AB) means preceded by AB
(?=)  Ex: (?=FG)  means followed by FG
These do not capture the matched portion.

Documantation: ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

You can use the Swift `String` `rangeOfString(pattern, options)` in place of `NSRegularExpression` which is much more involved.